# how to join table as a second level

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, join

I have a table with more then 6,000 rows that i need to "get" as join to other table.
I want this join to be as "second level" of the first level.
There is any way to do it?
(Not with eloquent, this make it very slow...)

for example:

```
$query = DB::table('first_table')
->join('second_table', 'first_table.id', '=', 'second_table.first_id')
->get();
```

What I get from this is:

```
[0] => [
    [id] => 1 
    [info] => true 
    [first_id] => 1 
    [something] => 929
]
[1] => [
    [id] => 2
    [info] => true 
    [first_id] => 2
    [something] => 1212
]
[2] => [
    [id] => 3
    [info] => true 
    [first_id] => 2
    [something] => 4444
]
```

What I **want** to get is:

```
[0] => [
    [id] => 1 
    [info] => true 
    [second_table] => [
         [first_id] => 1 
         [something] => 929
    ]
]
[1] => [
    [id] => 2
    [info] => true 
    [second_table] => [
         [first_id] => 2 
         [something] => 1212
    ]
]
[2] => [
    [id] => 3
    [info] => true 
    [second_table] => [
         [first_id] => 2 
         [something] => 4444
    ]
]
```

Comment: A query always only returns records, not multiple levels. If you want to format the data like that, you will have to map it yourself. Which is essentially what Eloquent does for you, but with more queries.

Comment: Do you have Eloquent models set up for `first_table` and `second_table`?

Comment: @Rwd The problem with Eloquent models is that its work very very slow

Comment: @philipxy what?